# How do I do URL rewriting SEO in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Let's say I have a page where you can view a book (cover image, author, title, ...). This is a PHP page.
So it is a dynamic generated page. When you follow this URL: https://mers.be/search?ID=202403150148 you can get there.

I want it to appear in Google as https://mers.be/search/Cataloging-the-World.-Paul-Otlet-and-the-Birth-of-the-Information-Age.html

So if the user searches "Cataloging the World" the link should appear in the search results.

Thx

to rewrite the link in ht access

Comment: Unless you want to create a specific rule for each single possible ID, you can't do all of this in .htaccess alone. You would need to modify your PHP script as well, so that it finds the relevant record via the text you are now passing in the URL, instead of the ID.

Comment: Also you should keep in mind that a google search (or any other catalog) does not only consider the URL path in crawled pages. But actually the header information provided _inside_ those pages. So you should check that your words are actually contained inside the head's title element for example.

Comment: How does `202403150148` relate to `Cataloging-the-World.-Paul-Otlet-and-the-Birth-of-the-Information-Age.html`? Is that date modified or a DB id? You also are working with PHP files already or HTML? I would remove punctuation, stop words, and extensions from the SEO friendly URLs as well.

Comment: 202403150148 is a DB id